# Verificar se há diferentes elementos em uma lista em R

Tags: r, lista, lapply

Eu tenho uma lista que cada elemento é um `data frame` contendo várias informações sobre um determinado instituidor de pensão. Na coluna `CLASSE` só pode haver um tipo e eu preciso saber quem possui mais de um tipo.  Como criar uma coluna que retorne TRUE caso o `INSTITUIDOR` possua pensionistas de diferentes classes.

Abaixo `dput` do `head` da lista:

```
structure(list(`1002538-1` = structure(list(ID.VINC.INST = c("1002538-1", 
"1002538-1"), DS_PREFIXO = c("FILHO (A) INVÁLIDO (A)", "VIÚVA"
), ID.FUNCIONAL = c(43189938L, 43189920L), NR_MATRICULA = c("0094712B", 
"0094712A"), NOME = c("RAQUEL ELCO CAMPOS", "CELINA ELCO CAMPOS"
), ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR = c(1002538L, 1002538L), VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR = c(1L, 
1L), NUMPENS = c(2L, 1L), NM_INSTITUIDOR = c("JOCELINO VILLELA CAMPOS", 
"JOCELINO VILLELA CAMPOS"), VL_BRUTO = c(1182.13, 1182.13), MES_REF = c("01/08/2017", 
"01/08/2017"), CLASSE = c("CLASSE 1", "CLASSE 1"), Freq = c(2L, 
2L)), .Names = c("ID.VINC.INST", "DS_PREFIXO", "ID.FUNCIONAL", 
"NR_MATRICULA", "NOME", "ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR", "VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR", 
"NUMPENS", "NM_INSTITUIDOR", "VL_BRUTO", "MES_REF", "CLASSE", 
"Freq"), row.names = 5:6, class = "data.frame"), `1003437-1` = structure(list(
    ID.VINC.INST = c("1003437-1", "1003437-1"), DS_PREFIXO = c("VIÚVA", 
    "DEPENDENTE"), ID.FUNCIONAL = c(44227795L, 44235089L), NR_MATRICULA = c("0416908A", 
    "0416908B"), NOME = c("VERGINIA MARIA DE OLIVEIRA ROSA", 
    "EMILLY DE OLIVEIRA ROSA"), ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR = c(1003437L, 
    1003437L), VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR = c(1L, 1L), NUMPENS = 1:2, 
    NM_INSTITUIDOR = c("ANTONIO PLACIDIO LOPES ROSA", "ANTONIO PLACIDIO LOPES ROSA"
    ), VL_BRUTO = c(3047.47, 3047.47), MES_REF = c("01/08/2017", 
    "01/08/2017"), CLASSE = c("CLASSE 1", "OUTRAS"), Freq = c(2L, 
    2L)), .Names = c("ID.VINC.INST", "DS_PREFIXO", "ID.FUNCIONAL", 
"NR_MATRICULA", "NOME", "ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR", "VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR", 
"NUMPENS", "NM_INSTITUIDOR", "VL_BRUTO", "MES_REF", "CLASSE", 
"Freq"), row.names = 10:11, class = "data.frame"), `10087958-1` = structure(list(
    ID.VINC.INST = c("10087958-1", "10087958-1"), DS_PREFIXO = c("VIÚVA", 
    "FILHO (A) MENOR"), ID.FUNCIONAL = c(50740172L, 50740202L
    ), NR_MATRICULA = c("", ""), NOME = c("ALEXANDRA GOMES DE OLIVEIRA MACIEL", 
    "JUAN PEDRO DE OLIVEIRA MACIEL"), ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR = c(10087958L, 
    10087958L), VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR = c(1L, 1L), NUMPENS = 1:2, 
    NM_INSTITUIDOR = c("MARCO ANTONIO DE OLIVEIRA MACIEL", "MARCO ANTONIO DE OLIVEIRA MACIEL"
    ), VL_BRUTO = c(3076.8, 3076.8), MES_REF = c("01/08/2017", 
    "01/08/2017"), CLASSE = c("CLASSE 1", "CLASSE 1"), Freq = c(2L, 
    2L)), .Names = c("ID.VINC.INST", "DS_PREFIXO", "ID.FUNCIONAL", 
"NR_MATRICULA", "NOME", "ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR", "VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR", 
"NUMPENS", "NM_INSTITUIDOR", "VL_BRUTO", "MES_REF", "CLASSE", 
"Freq"), row.names = 19:20, class = "data.frame"), `10114963-1` = structure(list(
    ID.VINC.INST = c("10114963-1", "10114963-1"), DS_PREFIXO = c("FILHO (A) MENOR", 
    "VIÚVA"), ID.FUNCIONAL = c(50853104L, 50853090L), NR_MATRICULA = c("", 
    ""), NOME = c("GUILHERME DE ASSIS MARINHO", "ELISANGELA DE ASSIS SILVA MARINHO"
    ), ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR = c(10114963L, 10114963L), VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR = c(1L, 
    1L), NUMPENS = c(2L, 1L), NM_INSTITUIDOR = c("EDSON BORBA MARINHO", 
    "EDSON BORBA MARINHO"), VL_BRUTO = c(3095.41, 3095.41), MES_REF = c("01/08/2017", 
    "01/08/2017"), CLASSE = c("CLASSE 1", "CLASSE 1"), Freq = c(2L, 
    2L)), .Names = c("ID.VINC.INST", "DS_PREFIXO", "ID.FUNCIONAL", 
"NR_MATRICULA", "NOME", "ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR", "VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR", 
"NUMPENS", "NM_INSTITUIDOR", "VL_BRUTO", "MES_REF", "CLASSE", 
"Freq"), row.names = 27:28, class = "data.frame"), `10179151-1` = structure(list(
    ID.VINC.INST = c("10179151-1", "10179151-1", "10179151-1"
    ), DS_PREFIXO = c("FILHO (A) MENOR", "COMPANHEIRA", "FILHO (A) MENOR"
    ), ID.FUNCIONAL = c(43038824L, 43300464L, 43038816L), NR_MATRICULA = c("0410258B", 
    "0410258C", "0410258A"), NOME = c("ERICA FERREIRA ROGERIO DE SOUZA", 
    "PATRICIA FERREIRA DA SILVA", "ERIC ROGERIO DE SOUZA JUNIOR"
    ), ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR = c(10179151L, 10179151L, 10179151L
    ), VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR = c(1L, 1L, 1L), NUMPENS = c(2L, 3L, 
    1L), NM_INSTITUIDOR = c("ERIC ROGERIO DE SOUZA", "ERIC ROGERIO DE SOUZA", 
    "ERIC ROGERIO DE SOUZA"), VL_BRUTO = c(416.04, 832.09, 416.04
    ), MES_REF = c("01/08/2017", "01/08/2017", "01/08/2017"), 
    CLASSE = c("CLASSE 1", "CLASSE 1", "CLASSE 1"), Freq = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L)), .Names = c("ID.VINC.INST", "DS_PREFIXO", "ID.FUNCIONAL", 
"NR_MATRICULA", "NOME", "ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR", "VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR", 
"NUMPENS", "NM_INSTITUIDOR", "VL_BRUTO", "MES_REF", "CLASSE", 
"Freq"), row.names = 40:42, class = "data.frame"), `1031945-1` = structure(list(
    ID.VINC.INST = c("1031945-1", "1031945-1"), DS_PREFIXO = c("FILHO (A) MENOR", 
    "FILHO (A) MENOR"), ID.FUNCIONAL = c(50840835L, 50840827L
    ), NR_MATRICULA = c("", ""), NOME = c("LUIZ SERGIO RAMOS TORRES", 
    "JULIANA RAMOS TORRES"), ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR = c(1031945L, 
    1031945L), VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR = c(1L, 1L), NUMPENS = c(2L, 
    1L), NM_INSTITUIDOR = c("ETEVALDO CORREA TORRES", "ETEVALDO CORREA TORRES"
    ), VL_BRUTO = c(656.83, 656.83), MES_REF = c("01/08/2017", 
    "01/08/2017"), CLASSE = c("CLASSE 1", "CLASSE 1"), Freq = c(2L, 
    2L)), .Names = c("ID.VINC.INST", "DS_PREFIXO", "ID.FUNCIONAL", 
"NR_MATRICULA", "NOME", "ID_FUNCIONAL_INSTITUIDOR", "VINCULO_INSTITUIDOR", 
"NUMPENS", "NM_INSTITUIDOR", "VL_BRUTO", "MES_REF", "CLASSE", 
"Freq"), row.names = 86:87, class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("1002538-1", 
"1003437-1", "10087958-1", "10114963-1", "10179151-1", "1031945-1"
))
```

Comment: Não compreendo completamente, quer a nova coluna em cada `data.frame`? Por exemplo, a primeira df tem duas linhas, ambas com a mesma classe, `CLASSE 1`. Quer uma nova coluna com ambos os valores `FALSE`?

Comment: Exatamente. A minha dificuldade neste problema é que cada `data frame` pode ter um diferente número de linhas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode não ser a forma mais elegante,

```
df <- data.frame(LISTA = names(dados), CLASSE = T)
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
 ifelse(length(unique(dados[[i]]$CLASSE)) == 1, df$CLASSE[i] <- F, df$CLASSE[i] <- T)
}
```

sendo `dados`, a lista que você forneceu.

Comment: Tive o seguinte erro: `Error in multpensao.semcotista[[i]]$CLASSE : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.

EDIT: Utilizei a variável errada aqui, já corrigi e deu certo. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 5):

A seguinte instrução `lapply` cria uma nova coluna chamada `DUPL_CLASSE` em cada `data.frame`. Se todos os valores da coluna `CLASSE` forem iguais, a nova coluna é toda `FALSE`, caso contrário é toda `TRUE`.

```
nova_lista <- lapply(lista, function(x){
        x$DUPL_CLASSE <- length(unique(x$CLASSE)) > 1
        x
    })
```

(Eu chamei `lista` à lista da pergunta.)